# Is there a way to use a standalone WireMock with Handlebars partials?

Tags: integration-testing, wiremock, handlebars.java

I would like to use handlebars partials in [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/). Unfortunately I can't find a way to register those in the [docs](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/).

Comment: They added it in newer versions. http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently there is no support for HandleBars Partials in WireMock.

HandleBars is supported in the Response Template transformer and feature is handled as an extension. In the GitHub the [ResponsTemplateTransformer.java](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/extension/responsetemplating/ResponseTemplateTransformer.java) handles the processing.

It's functionality can be extended using WireMock HandleBars 'helpers'. These are extensions documented on the [Custom extensions page](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#customer-helpers) (bottom of the page) and examples in the GitHub code can be found here: [responsetemplateing/helpers](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/tree/4326757f1c3982b5a02af7b2d74021262bca6b48/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/extension/responsetemplating/helpers)